# Is the Universe 11 billion years old?

Tags: cosmology, time, space-expansion, big-bang

[This clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiSwvxA5v4Q) claims scientists found a star 200M years older than the Universe. However, I took another assertion more seriously: scientists estimated a faster expansion rate of the Universe, driving age down to **11.4B years**.

The clip cites no sources whatsoever, so I looked further; not much out there, and the most remotely credible was [this phys.org](https://phys.org/news/2018-08-universe-expansion-dispute-physics.html) article, attesting to a disagreement on rate of expansion. Found no actual scientific publications.

So what's the *real* state of affairs on the matter? Are we still highly uncertain on the 13.8B figure, or are the lesser figures based on a different definition of "age"? (Or maybe it's pop hype nonsense)

Comment: It's quite difficult to measure Hubble's constant accurately, as the whole universe is fluid. Despite that, we are pretty confident that the current values measured have errors significantly < 10%. The hardest part is, however, estimating past values of the Hubble constant. (Note that the Hubble time is ~ 14B years). While I think the [Wikipedia articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_the_universe) is a bit overconfident, pretty much every relevant study yielded between 13 and 14.5 By.

Comment: @mostanes that looks like an answer to me

Comment: The commonly accepted estimation of the age of the universe might be wrong, see here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/514882/why-is-the-planck-wmap-estimate-of-the-age-of-the-universe-preferred/514911#514911