# Is the commonly accepted Universe age of 13.8B years really accurate?

Tags: cosmology, universe, big-bang, cosmic-microwave-background, dark-energy

Hmm...challenging the error margin of a specific calculation result of a specific model based on confirmed inconsistencies is regarded as "opinion-based". Interesting. Just curious, is the rationale of closing a "opinion-based" question also "opinion-based"?

---

According to the calculation of the cosmological standard model $\Lambda CDM$, the age of the Universe is 13.8B years old. This claim is more or less supported by observation of oldest galaxies/stars in the universe.

But is 13.8B really accurate as inferred by $\Lambda CDM$?

Recently there were alarming inconsistencies turning up regarding the Universe's late-time history at low redshift, evidenced by the contradicting numbers of Hubble constant ($H_0$) measured by supernovae/cepheid variable ladders with what is predicted by $\Lambda CDM$ which is calibrated from CMB (Cosmic microwave background) observations and BAO (Baryon acoustic oscillations) constraints. This contradiction is called Hubble tension, or even "Hubble crisis" according to some cosmologists.

If the Hubble tension turns out not to be a systematic measurement error, it could have real implications on the accuracy of dark energy density ($\Omega_\Lambda$) and the true age of the Universe. The standard cosmology model $\Lambda CDM$ has been known as the "concordance model". Given the "Hubble tension" and other inconsistencies (e.g. the controversy surrounding $\sigma_8$), are we sure  $\Lambda CDM$ is a "concordance model"?

Shall we take $\Lambda CDM$'s calculation of the Universe being 13.8B years young with a grain of salt? Should we put a much higher error margin on the claimed age number? In other words, I am questioning that when the Hubble tension is eventually resolved, a new value for the age might exceed the bounds of the commonly agreed +/- uncrtainty error that accompanies the 13.8B value.

---

Added note: see a related question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/514882/why-is-the-planck-wmap-estimate-of-the-age-of-the-universe-preferred?rq=1).

Comment: I think this question is impossible to answer, since almost by definition we don't know the source of the Hubble tension, not to mention any unforeseen new physics which could alter the calculation of the age of the universe.

Comment: Not qualified to answer, but this might point you in a helpful direction: https://www.livescience.com/universe-expansion-atacama-hubble-constant-measurement.html.

Comment: @Tony, thanks for providing the link! By "It is 13.77 billion years old, give or take 40 million years", did they factor in the "Hubble tension"-related uncertainties when they say "give or take 40 million years"?

Comment: I don't think the estimate factors in the Hubble tension.  It provides more evidence that the CMB measurements are not subject to _measurement_ errors, but as the article says there could still be problems with the theoretical approach used to go from measurements to age.

Comment: @Tony, right, the CMB "measurement" seems to be fine. The issue lies in the "theoretical approach". Currently there is a plethora of newfangled fixing patches for $\Lambda$CMD (just like what your car repair mechanic did to your 1978 Kia), in an attempt to salvage $\Lambda$CMD one way or another.

Comment: Are you asking if the +/- uncrtainty error that accompanies the 13.8B value provides a reasonable prediction of a new value for the age when the Hubble tension is eventually solved?  Or do you have a different concept in mind regarding "accurate"?

Comment: @Buzz, I am questioning that  "when the Hubble tension is eventually solved", "a new value for the age" might exceed the bounds of the commonly agreed "+/- uncrtainty error that accompanies the 13.8B value".

Comment: You just do NOT ask a lady her age. Mother Nature is very sensitive about that...

Comment: I have not done the calculations, but I'm fairly certain that the 13.8 billion years (& error) quoted is from Planck data. Therefore if one uses the local universe value of the Hubble constant, one will get a different estimate of the age of the universe (& error). Which is correct, we currently do not know. Still it's probable that the order of magnitude is correct - the universe could be younger, but probably not by a lot.

Comment: @Allure, if we use the higher Hubble constant from the local universe measurement and get a younger universe age, would that be in conflict with the oldest globular cluster age and create another tension?

Comment: @MadMax again I have not done the calculations, but I suspect there is no tension with globular cluster ages even with the larger value of the Hubble constant simply because if there were, I would've seen it. Most probably, the difference in the estimated age of the universe is not large enough.

Comment: @Allure, you know some globular clusters are very close to the upper boundary of the universe age. Therefore, a smidgen of decrease in the universe age could potentially create another tension in cosmology. I gather cosmology is currently besieged by a couple of tensions, hence cosmologist might prefer keeping the embarrassing prospect of further tensions just to themselves.

Comment: @MadMax if cosmologists were really keeping embarrassing tensions to themselves, you would never have heard of the Hubble tension.

Comment: Although not involved in the decision, I believe the question was closed as "opinion-based" because it referred to "the Universe" rather than "our local universe", "the local universe" or "the multiverse":  Some persons may feel that the capitalization makes that clear, but the usage, in English, is generally to capitalize the larger, more important, or more generally-accepted of two entities:  For instance, the deity of monotheistic religion ("God") is capitalized, but the word with the same spelling is not  capitalized when it's describing any individual deity in pantheistic religions.

Comment: As edits cost points if rejected by the Originating Person, it will, as far as I'm concerned, be up to them to change the capitalization or terminology in their question's title.  I can't tell whether it's intentionally implying a "creation event" that's not relevant to physics, as I've seen the same deviation from English usage among physicists whose native language is not English.

Comment: Before cosmologists began (in 1981) formulating inflationary models, which generally provide for local universes in a multiverse (that, in Aguirre & Gratton's "Steady-state eternal inflation" and, by at least some readings of them, in Poplawski's "Cosmology with torsion" and Penrose's "Conformal Cyclic Cosmology" as well, are eternal to the past as well as to the future), the question would've been presented without capitalization of the word "universe":  Its capitalization would've been meaningless, like capitalizing the word "world".  However, complete eternality implies infinity in GR.

Comment: @Allure, "if cosmologists were really keeping embarrassing tensions to themselves", well, in your very answer below, your calculated universe age is possibly in tension with the $\Lambda$CMD model. Is it a bit inconvenient for you to explicitly mention the tension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The significance of the tension is not that the age measurement is off by much, but rather such a tension strongly suggests that we have not yet correctly understood all the relevant physics. So the most likely outcome is that the physics gets understood better and all the age measurements turn out to be roughly right, just not quite as accurate as has been estimated on the basis of the models used so far.

I am not working directly in this area, so I cannot give an estimate of what the range of uncertainty might be. But it is clear from the publications that the Planck collaboration published measured values of cosmological parameters based on assumptions which included, among others: that if there is any spatial curvature, it is negligible; that if there is any local flow or other such inhomogeneities in the cosmic fluid, then its effects are negligible; that the dark energy has the form of a cosmological constant; various things to do with neutrinos and lensing which I don't claim to know much about. As soon as one allows that things like this cannot necessarily be assumed, one will get bigger error margins. So it seems to me that the error margins published by them are indeed a bit misleading, but I am not able to assess what would be a fairer statement. I note that Di Valentino, Melchiorri and Silk (2015) published a comparison of a 6-parameter model and a 12-parameter model. The error margin in the baryon density parameter in the 12-parameter model is twice what it is in the 6-parameter model. The error margin in the cosmological constant in the 12-parameter model is about 4 times larger than in the 6-parameter model.
The error margin in the Hubble parameter in the 12-parameter model is $4.8$ times larger than in the 6-parameter model. Yes that's $4.8$ times.

So this indicates the kind of thing that can happen. More work has been done since then, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please elaborate on how "not quite as accurate as has been estimated". In particular, what is the error margin of the universe age if the uncertainties related to the Hubble tension is taken into account?

Comment: @MadMax I added a paragraph; that's about the sum of my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you Andrew! I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

With $H = 73 km/s/Mpc$, the age of the universe is [about 13.4 billion years](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/astro801/content/l10_p5.html), a number still comfortably above the age of the oldest globular clusters.

Caveat: this estimate was obtained by taking the inverse of the Hubble constant, which is a cruder way of estimating the age of the universe since it doesn't take into account the density of matter, radiation & dark energy. It is still a reasonable estimate however, and illustrates how much changing the Hubble constant might change the age estimate.

Comment: Thanks for providing a rough estimation of the universe age based on the local measurement of the Hubble constant. According to Wikipedia, the universe age is "13.787±0.020 billion years within the Lambda-CDM concordance model as of 2018". So is the estimation of  "about 13.4 billion years" outside the error margin of the concordance model?

Comment: @MadMax yes. What exactly is your question though? It should be obvious that 13.4 is outside the error margin of 13.787 +/- 0.02.

Comment: Do you have any reference to the latest age estimation (as of 2018 or later) of the oldest globular clusters? In addition to the age estimation, I am interested in the error margins as well.

Comment: @MadMax try Googling for it and adding a restriction of, say, results from the past year. https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.06594

Comment: Thank you for providing the link! According to the paper "we find an age of the Universe tU=13.5+0.16−0.14(stat.)±0.5(sys.) at 68\% confidence level, accounting for the formation time of globular clusters and its uncertainty." So your estimation of "13.4 billion years" would sit comfortably within the error margin of above globular-clusters-based estimation, right?

Comment: @MadMax I'm finding your questions tedious and so will not be answering them anymore. If you really do not know how to tell if 13.4 billion is within the error margin of 13.5 billion +0.16 -0.14 +/- 0.5, ask a new question.

Comment: Of course I know the answers to these questions to you. The point is for the benefit of the other readers interested in the same question, so that they know what has been discussed. In your answer text, could you please make a conclusion by comparing your estimation with the error margins of the Lambda-CDM model (which is outside the error boundary) and globular cluster estimation (including the link), respectively. After that, I will accept the answer. I understand it might be "obvious" and sometimes "tedious" for your highness, but it is for the the benefit of the other readers. Thanks!